# Mocha await/async handling (expected) errors

Tags: javascript, error-handling, async-await, mocha.js

Some time ago I was curious on how to execute async tests using Mocha and those tests to expect an error as a result (see [Mocha async test handle errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747081/mocha-async-test-handle-errors))

Now I tried the same for the newer version of nodejs using await/async. Just a simple case but as I need to wrap the code in a `try / catch` block, things get out of hand.

After long hours of testing I ended up with a solution but it doesn't look good.

So I'm looking for a better way to do this.

The test looks like this:

```
it('myTest', async function () {

  // THIS WORKS => CODE OPTION 1:
  // this works, it uses promises but not await/async
  return somePromiseFunction()
    .then(() => Promise.reject(new Error('Expected method to reject.')))
    .catch(err => assert.ok(err instanceof Error, 'This should be an error!'));


  // THIS WORKS => CODE OPTION 2:
  // this works, it uses await/async
  let forceFail = false;
  try {
    await somePromiseFunction();
    forceFail = true;
  } catch (err) {}
  if (forceFail) assert.ok(false, 'Expected method to reject.');


  // WONT WORK => CODE OPTION 3:
  try {
    await somePromiseFunction();
    assert.ok(false, 'you shouln\'t be here');
  } catch (err) {
    assert.ok(err instanceof Error, 'This should be an error!');
  }

});
```

Both option 1 and 2 work. Option 1 uses classic `Promise.then.catch` syntax, and that's ok. Option 2 was the only way for me to make things work but is very complex to understand / maintain. It relies on a sort of global variable and handling states, and it just doesn't look good.

There is an option 3 in the code, but it does not work. Something like that would be easy to read but it does not work at all, not the first assert nor the second one.

If you remove the `try / catch` block then it won't work either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way, but you'll need to upgrade to node version 10. I was using 8, but this new feature included in assert solves my problem in an elegant way.

Instead of trying this:

```
// WONT WORK => CODE OPTION 3:
try {
  await somePromiseFunction();
  assert.ok(false, 'you shouln\'t be here');
} catch (err) {
  assert.ok(err instanceof Error, 'This should be an error!');
}
```

Do this:

```
// this works!
await assert.rejects(
  async () => somePromiseFunction(),
  Error
);
```

You can also verify the type of error being thrown, but in my case `Error` will suffice.

EDIT: `async () =>` was not really necessary, I ended up with a one line assert (second parameter is optional, but I'd rather keep it):

```
await assert.rejects(somePromiseFunction(), Error);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the third option, `err` would always be `undefined` since you're catching the exception as `e`, not as `err`. And the assert would always fail because `undefined` is not an instance of `Error`.

Comment: That was just a typo. The real problem is that they coding style for async/await uses try/catch and when throwing an error or an assertion it will be handled by the `catch` so it will not be a real error for mocha.